# how to count Usb port using java?

Tags: java, sockets

I want to detect list of USB Ports which are free *(not occupied)* in system to while I checked with `CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()` while this returns me Enumeration with 0 elements
I'd add librxtxcomm.jar too in classpath.

This should return each Port detail

```
Enumeration pList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers(); 
System.out.println(pList.hasMoreElements());
```

this returns 0 mean no List/Enumeration.

Rest Code :

```
public class CommPortLister{

    /** Simple test program. */
    public static void main(String[] ap) {
        new CommPortLister().list();
    }

    /** Ask the Java Communications API * what ports it thinks it has. */
    protected void list() {
        // get list of ports available on this particular computer, by calling static method in CommPortIdentifier.

        System.out.println("");
        Enumeration pList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
        System.out.println("Before While");
        // CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers(); 
        // Process the list.
        System.out.println(pList.hasMoreElements());

        while (pList.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println("While Loop");
            CommPortIdentifier cpi = (CommPortIdentifier) pList.nextElement();
            System.out.print("Port " + cpi.getName() + " ");
            if (cpi.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
                System.out.println("is a Serial Port: " + cpi);
            } else if (cpi.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_PARALLEL)  {
                System.out.println("is a Parallel Port: " + cpi);
            } else  {
                System.out.println("is an Unknown Port: " + cpi);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("After While");
    }
}
```

Code to detect USB port while i am unable to detect USB Port

Comment: i want to make java program which should return me number of available CPU port. is it possible?

Comment: CPUs don't have ports...

Comment: @BoltClock ... tell me where u attach your pendrive?

Comment: On a USB port, which doesn't have anything to do with the CPU. As others have mentioned, you probably meant hardware ports. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @BoltClock i want to know how many Hardware ports are free in machine using java program .. this is my question

Answer (score 1):

A port number is a 16-bit unsigned integer, thus ranging from 1 to 65535. 
If you need to know which ports are occupied, you may call the system command "netstat" from java.

================Edited===========================
The above information is for transport layer logical ports.If you are looking  for hardware ports for peripheral devices, then you need to check the COM ports. I found the following tutorial, maybe you can give it a try, so find another tutorial that suits your need.

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=11

You will need javax.comm api for this. You can grab it from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomm20jar.htm or http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html

Comment: will it return me cpu port number?

Comment: If by CPU port number, you are meaning the hardware ports, I have edited my answer with some information on that. Please check.

Comment: i have try above tutorial. is there any jar file required for that code?

Comment: I have edited the post and updated the jars needed. Please accept the answer if this serves your purpose.

Comment: i have accept your ans but will it gives me. which port is busy in CPU and Which is Available?

Comment: And You also upvote my question.. because few people thinks that this is use less question

Comment: This code is not mine. Objective was to show you some code about how to scan hardwire ports so that you can implement your own logic. This code for example will check some port and print inputs if any.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using ServerSocket(portNo). If there is an service running in the port, it will error so catch the exception and try the next port.

Answer (score -1):

Well here the thing using that u can have available ports u can scan it.

```
public class GettingAvaliable {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int startPortRange = 0;
        int stopPortRange = 65365;
        int usedport = 0;
        int unusedports = 0;

        for (int i = startPortRange; i <= stopPortRange; i++) {
            try {
                Socket ServerSok = new Socket("127.0.0.1", i);
                System.out.println("Port in use: " + i);
                usedport++;
                ServerSok.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();

            }
            System.out.println("Port not in use: " + i);
            unusedports++;
            if (i == stopPortRange) {
                System.out.println("Number of Used Ports In Your Machine: "+usedport);
                System.out.println("Number of Unused Ports In Your Machine: "+unusedports);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its means that local PC means its default of your Computer Localhost.

Comment: Whenever u get Exception means that port can not connect and its Refuses connection.

Comment: ya i know all computer have hardware port that number.

Comment: i run your code it give me lots of exception... i dont know how to deal with your program..  how i can identify my which port is free?

Comment: when ever u getting Number of port like when u getting Exception means that port is in use. and when u getting Num printed that means that port is free. :)

Comment: suppose i have 4 hardware port in my computer and i have attach 1 pen drive in amoung 4, then it should return me 1 port is busy and 3 are available.. this is my requirement

Comment: ya its giving if u can see it whole program once.

Comment: what is stopPortRange?

Comment: Just Debug that Program and See that it will give out put as Port in use: ** when port is in use and Port not in use: 22 when port not in use.

Comment: if u know that number of ports are there in PC then that is stopPortRange.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the IP address of machine?

Comment: Its Localhost ya it is default ip for your machine. u can say that it is.

Comment: ohk . i have set my ip address in code but i dont get any single msg like "Port in use".every time it prints "Port not in use".

Comment: Look i have updated Code according to the your Requirement and just dont Replace that ip bcoz that is for default machine. if u change it it will not give Out put.

Comment: now it run proper .. Number of Used Ports In Your Machine: 7 is  this actual output. how should i test or cross verify?

Comment: just go to http://whatismyipaddress.com/ and take your ip and put it there in place of 127.0.0.1 and u will get by IP :)

Comment: i have set my ip and run program it give me following output, 
Port in use: 80
Port in use: 8009
Port in use: 9090
Port in use: 35462
Port in use: 43939
Number of Used Ports In Your Machine: 5

Comment: ya that is Right out out. what i want to get more?

Comment: how to identify port with port number number.. i get 35462 means which port?

Comment: it self it is port and number. u know na how many port does computer have. ? so it self its port number.

Comment: ohk...is it hardware portnumber?  i think this is logical port number/server port number like 8080,9090... i want port number where we attach mouse,pendrive..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51569/discussion-between-java-man-and-krishna)

Comment: Yes its Logical Port number.

Comment: i want physical port number.. i want to detect how many usb port are there in system... is it posible using this code?

Comment: May be i am not sure that is possible or not but it has to be let me see again...

Comment: ok tell me .. your answer will help me for next process thank you

Comment: For sure may be it will need time for do this may be an hour